# Expect 'struct netif *' but argument is of type 'struct netif *'

Tags: c

I get the following error with gcc when I declare a `struct netif *` from a function scope (where the compile doesn't complain) to global scope:

```
src/main.c:114:3: warning: passing argument 1 of 'low_level_init' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
src/main.c:62:13: note: expected 'struct netif *' but argument is of type 'struct netif *'
```

Why is does compiler give the following "non-sensical" complaint?

`expected 'stuct netif *' but argument is of type 'struct netif *'`

Comment: Please post the code for a minimal repro of this compile error

Comment: In addition to a minimal, complete example that reproduces the error it might be helpful to know which version of GCC this is. Is it a snapshot/pre-release included with some distribution? The warning style looks fairly recent.

Comment: Maybe the definition for `struct netif` in scope at both places is for a different one?

Comment: @pmg - I thought gcc had a different warning for that. (I don't think I can even think of a way to make it not an error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "full program"

```
void foonetif(struct netif *dst) {
  if (dst) return;
  return;
}

struct netif {
  double bar;
};

int main(void) {
  struct netif *netif = 0; /* NULL */
  foonetif(netif);
  return 0;
}
```

generates this output from `gcc 10398683.c` (gcc version 4.6.3), so with all default options

```
10398683.c:1:22: warning: ‘struct netif’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
10398683.c:1:22: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
10398683.c: In function ‘main’:
10398683.c:12:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘newnetif’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
10398683.c:1:6: note: expected ‘struct netif *’ but argument is of type ‘struct netif *’
```

Note the last warning (really a note) :)

Comment: code golf (compiles on my gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1): `void foo(struct bar* pst){}; void main() { foo((struct bar*)0); }` :)

Comment: Why is this an answer and not an edit to the question? And why is it posted by pmg rather than OP? I'm confused...

Comment: @R..: It seems that pmg managed to get a minimal test case.

Comment: @R..: this is an answer because I couldn't think of a way to say it in a comment. I meant it as an example that gives the OP's "warning".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is scope. The first `struct netif` is in the scope of the function's argument list, and goes out of scope after that function ends. The second `struct netif` is defined in a new scope. These are thereby different structure types with different tags which happen to have the same name. Just like `int i;` and `int i;` in two different functions are different variables that happen to have the same name.

Comment: Hum. Can't global scope `struct`s be used by a function in function scope?

Comment: Yes, but they have to be declared first in the file scope.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting question; have fallen foul of this myself; [mostly due to horrid hacks involving dubious type casts on innocent memory-blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

This answer is really just a corollary to [R's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) answer, which pretty much nails the issue (though i'm not quite sure about the `and goes out of scope after that function ends..` bit)

For me, the key to this is perusal of:

(1) [ISO C99 6.7.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> Two types have compatible type if their types are the same. Additional
>   rules for determining whether two types are compatible are described
>   in 6.7.2 for type specifiers,  in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers, and in
>   6.7.5 for declarators.46) Moreover, two structure,   union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible
>   if their  tags and members satisfy the following requirements: If one
>   is declared with a tag, the other shall be declared with the same tag. ...

(2) [C namespaces](http://www.dmst.aueb.gr/dds/cscout/doc/name.html)

Anyway, here's some code (~a couple of translation units) that hopefully demonstrates some possibly *surprising* behaviour for those that haven't yet hit this issue before:

blah.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct bar  {int a; int b;} stbar; 
struct bar_ {int a; int d;} stbar_; 

void foo(struct bar* pst);
void foo_(struct bar st);


void callfoo() 
{ 
    /*no warnings; possibly surprising results ! */
    stbar.a=313;
    stbar.b=31313;
    foo(&stbar);
    printf("called foo() with stbar:  %d, %d\n", stbar.a, stbar.b);

    /*generates incompatible types warnings:
    blah.c:23:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    blah.c:6:6: note: expected ‘struct bar *’ but argument is of type ‘struct bar_ *’    */
    stbar_.a=313;
    stbar_.d=31313;
    foo(&stbar_);
    printf("called foo() with stbar_: %d, %d\n", stbar_.a, stbar_.d);


    /*generates incompatible types warnings:
    blah.c:31:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    blah.c:6:6: note: expected ‘struct bar *’ but argument is of type ‘struct bar *’      */
    struct bar  {float s; float t;} stbar; 
    foo(&stbar);
    printf("called foo() with locally defined stbar:  %f, %f\n", stbar.s, stbar.t);    
}


void callfoo_()
{
    stbar.a=313;
    stbar.b=31313;

    //passing in incompatible type by value ~ no warnings; possibly surprising results ! 
    foo_(stbar); 

    /*uncomenting next line generates compiler error: 
    blah.c:47:5: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘foo_’
    blah.c:7:6: note: expected ‘struct bar’ but argument is of type ‘struct bar_’     */
    //foo_(stbar_); 
}


void main() 
{
    callfoo();
    callfoo_();
}
```

blah_.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct bar {int x; float z;} stbar; 

void foo(struct bar* pst)
{
    printf("foo : %d, %f\n", pst->x, pst->z);
    pst->x=13;
    pst->z=13.13;
}

void foo_(struct bar st)
{
    printf("foo_ : %d, %f\n", st.x, st.z);
    st.x=13;
    st.z=13.13;
}
```

output:

```
$ gcc  blah.c blah_.c
blah.c: In function ‘callfoo’:
blah.c:23:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
blah.c:6:6: note: expected ‘struct bar *’ but argument is of type ‘struct bar_ *’
blah.c:31:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
blah.c:6:6: note: expected ‘struct bar *’ but argument is of type ‘struct bar *’

$ ./a.out
foo : 313, 0.000000
called foo() with stbar:  13, 1095898235
foo : 313, 0.000000
called foo() with stbar_: 13, 1095898235
foo : 13274075, 0.000000
called foo() with locally defined stbar:  0.000000, 13.130000
foo_ : 313, 0.000000

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1 ...
```

Corollary of corollary: praise the gods for C++ `namespace`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your "full program" wont compile.

struct netif is not declared before foonetif which uses it.  Try moving the struct definition before its first use.

Comment: The "full program" compiles just fine (albeit with warnings). Notice that what is used in `foonetif` is a pointer, not an object of type `struct netif`.

Comment: The compiler will create an 'empty' `struct netif` for itself when it first comes across one if there hasn't been one defined yet.  When it comes across a real definition, they don't match.  Therefore you get the warning.  

I suspect this wouldn't work if you compiled it as C++ rather than C.